# Scrolling with Javascript inside of an overflow element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I need to do scrolling with JS. I know it can be done on the window with `window.scrollBy` or `window.scrollTo`, but I haven't been able to find how to get it done inside of an element that has the `overflow-y: scroll` css property. Here's a JSBin as an example of what I want to scroll: http://jsbin.com/UcUQul/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scrollTop` property. For instance:

```
var outer = document.getElementById('outer');
outer.scrollTop = 10;
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wgzmn/) for an example.

Comment: I don't want to scroll on the window, I want to scroll inside the div.

Comment: @tzenderman - "window" is just a name of the `<div>` you've used in your code. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wgzmn/) for an example.